# django - how do i use annotations with signals?

Tags: django

Or rather, I have the old double-import problem with Django and signals when i include the signals.py from models.py

I'd rather not have to put the "run only once" code in for the signals, but i  might do that if i *absolutely* have to. It just seems like such a stupid hack.

Anyway,

given i have a signals.py file AND one of the signals is for one of the objects defined in  models.py, HOW do i create the annotation for it?

If i include the model then i get the ol' "circular reference" problem that Python, confusingly, still seems to be tripped up by. It is only 2012 though.

I experimented with using get_model, but that doesn't seem to work... the signal is now called for *all* saves on *any and all* models in the models.py file.

Here is the annotation, and what it looks like now:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=get_model('myapp.models','Story'))
```

i also tried

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Story)
```

with a corresponding `from myapp.models import Story` above, but caused the import error described.

What do i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When stuck like this, I just register the receiver without specifying a sender, and do the model import inside the function body.

```
@receiver(pre_save)
def handler(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    from models import MyModel
    if not isinstance(sender, MyModel):
        return
    do_stuff()
```